# Checking if the user logged in the controller _construct function (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is very small question but I want to know is it good way to do.

I am checking if the user logged-in in a separate controller and if logged-in I am saving it to session and this way I am checking it in every admin page and it is also working well. is this best practice to do?

```
function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin/about_us_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $is_logged = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged');
        if (!$is_logged) {
            redirect('admins', 'refresh');
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @Prashant - Just to know Is this best way to do this? :)

Comment: No question for stackoverflow imho.

Comment: make it in your common file like header

Comment: Maybe you will get more help on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approch is good to check if the user is logged-in in the constructor function of the controller. there is one thing you can do to save resources which is to do all that login check before you load any models and libraries.

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $is_logged = $this->session->userdata('admin_logged');
    if (!$is_logged) {
        redirect('admins', 'refresh');
    }
    $this->load->model('admin/about_us_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```